# How to add functionality in payroll plugin of OrangeHrm?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4, orangehrm

I have made a "Payroll" module and the functionality of that module also made with php files but I need to integrate that php files into orange hrm. so now here the problem comes for because I can't understand where to start in orangehrm to integrate it. I know start from index.php after that edit where to get my module withing the footer and header of the OrangeHRM.

And can anyone explain me to find the path of this line

Answer (score 0):

orangehrm is based in symfony (framework MVC), if you wanna add a module, need:

1. create a folder in (symfony\plugins...)
2. enable the plugin in setting.yml (\apps\orangehrm\config\setting.yml)
3. add the module in databases ( use phpmyadmin for this)
4. add the module in lib
5. logout, delete cache and login back.

this is way for 3.1 versions. That version of the software you are using?